# how to show text that can not be selected/copy using react

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I noticed some sites publish text that no one can select or copy. How can this be achieved in React? is it possible? Sometimes I believe they are using some images but this might be a solution that uses too many bytes.

Comment: I feel this requires the standard disclaimer that *any* technique that tries to keep the user from copying-and-pasting content is, at best, a simplistic stop-gap that will only deter the laziest of users.  If you send a piece of content to my browser, and I feel compelled to copy it, I can.  Period.

Comment: @AdamNathanielDavis That is true, however, let's say I'm building a virtual windowing system (which I actually am right now) and the user accidentally selects a bunch of text in titlebars while dragging windows around, then what will they do? Clicking the window may not have any effect after already selecting the text due to other code so I guess they're just stuck with a bunch of ugly colored text on their screen until they refresh the page. Unfortunate.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`user-select: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) on the elements you don't want to be selectable by the user.

```js
function App() {
  return <div style={{ userSelect: "none" }}>Unselectable text</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Unselectable text - drag selected copied and pasted from your code snippet ‍♂️. Likely a browser dependent issue here: on Safari